# VBA open IE as invisible is not working

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to open IE in background as below, but after 2 or 3 pages navigation it is taking more time to navigate and it moving in the loop

```
For k= 2 to lr
check_w:
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate Sheets("sheet1").Range("E" & k).Value
ie.Visible = False
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
check_webpage:
Set BDoc = Nothing
Web_app_Title = Sheets("sheet1").Range("E" & k).Value
search_WEB_APP_URL
If BDoc Is Nothing Then
    If ie Is Nothing Then
         Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
         GoTo check_w
    Else
        GoTo check_webpage
   End If
End If
next k
```

Answer (score 0):

A new IE-instance is created by in every iteration of your loop.
Set `ie.visible = True` for testing or open a Windows Task Manager, and you see what i mean.

So, quite simply, create the IE-object **once** before entering the loop. After finishing the loop, quit it before setting `ie = Nothing`.

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

For k= 2 to lr
    ie.navigate Sheets("sheet1").Range("E" & k).Value
    ....
Next k

ie.quit
Set ie = nothing
```

Should your experience problems with your IE-object getting dropped (for whatever reason), then, by any means, you can still wrap something like

```
If ie = Nothing Then Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

inside the loop.

Hint: instead of `Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))` I used something like `While ie.busy = True` in Powershell - not sure if that applies in VBA too.

EDIT: `Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4 : Loop`